# Store Change History

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, blazor

I have been building a web application using Blazor, on the site thre is a change history/audit area which records every change made on which every tab is open showing basic information, user name, date, old value, new value etc. Right now all the changes are being logged in the connected SQL Server, as you can imagine this means the size of the data base could increase rapidly. Rather than running a script that clears out old history every few weeks is there anyway I could direct the change history logs to another SQL database or some other cloud storage. Not looking for any code example just ideas of how/if this might be possible.
Thanks.

Comment: *"is there anyway I could direct the change history logs to another SQL database or some other cloud storage"* Many, yes... Should you though? Probably not if you want to be able to query this data alongside the production data easily at the same time. This just feels like you should have good data/log retention policies.

Comment: No, I can't imagine that "this means the size of the data base could increase rapidly."  You could run SQL on the kind of data you're talking about for years, and not make much of a dent in your drive space.  The bigger the database gets, the more value it has, because you can find new ways to go through the data later.  For example, I run an edu-site, and I recorded all students' answers, even though I wasn't really doing anything with them.  LATER, I realized that I could run statistical analysis on all that data to rank both students AND question difficulty.  Lucky I didn't throw it out.

Comment: Thanks both for your inputs I'll bring this up with my manager about how this could cause a few issues down the line in in respects of being able to query the data and how it shouldn't cause that many issues when it comes to how much space it takes up. I think their concerns with space lies with the fact that we will potenially be having thousands of lines of data in the change history because one feature of the site tracks bank transactions. Thankyou both again!